# fetching data from multiple mysql tables through nodejs into hbs file

Tags: mysql, node.js, handlebars.js

hello i have three different mysql tables in my mysql database and iam trying to  fetch data from these three mysql tables  through nodejs into my homepage without joining,i used UNION for this issue,i tried one sql query for that but its not working its just giving me data only from first table and not from other tables. what will be the right syntax for this issue?

**homepage**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <base href='/'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>homepage</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark p-3">
        <h3 class="navbar text-white">Homepage</h3>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarresponsive"
            aria-controls="navbarresponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="/" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a href="/post/register" class="nav-link">Register</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a href="/post/login" class="nav-link">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>
    {{!-- jumbotron --}}
    <div class="container gap-1">

        {{#each userData}}
        <h4>{{title}}</h4>
        <h4>{{status}}</h4>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <img src="http://localhost:5000/images/upload_images/{{images}}" alt="" class="" width="100" height="100">
        <video src="http://localhost:5000/images/videos/{{video}}" width="340" height="240" type="video/mp4"></video>

        {{/each}}


    </div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**routes for homepage**

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const db = require("../config/db_config");
const { ensureAuthenticated } = require("../config/auth");

//  homepage
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    db.query(
        "SELECT a.title, a.status, a.description FROM posts a UNION ALL SELECT b.images,b.age,b.address FROM images b UNION ALL SELECT c.video,c.address,c.landmark FROM videos c",
        (err, results) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(results);
            res.render("index", {
                userData: results,
            });
        }
    );
});

// profile page
router.get("/profile", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render("profile");
});

// route for update data
router.post("/update", (req, res) => {
    let sql =
        "UPDATE posts SET title ='" +
        req.body.title +
        "', status='" +
        req.body.status +
        "', description='" +
        req.body.description +
        "' WHERE id=" +
        req.body.id;

    let query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.redirect("/post/spost");
    });
});

// //route for delete data
router.post("/delete", (req, res) => {
    let sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id=" + req.body.id + "";
    db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.redirect("/post/spost");
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```